# Ruby - Intersection of two collections, which are attributes of two different objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have 3 classes defined as:

Client

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :provider
  has_many :meeting_times
end
```

Provider

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :clients
  has_many :meeting_times
end
```

MeetingTime

```
class MeetingTime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :meetingable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Each instance of MeetingTime has a day, start_time and end_time.
Is there a way for me to efficiently compute the intersection of

```
client_instance1.meeting_times and provider_instance1.meeting_times
```

In my seed file, I create meeting_times for clients and providers as follows

```
client_instance1.meeting_times.build(:day => "Friday", :start_time => time1, :end_time => time2)
client_instance1.meeting_times.build(:day => "Saturday", :start_time => time3, :end_time => time4)
client_instance1.save!
```

Currently when I try

```
client_instance1.meeting_times & provider_instance1.meeting_times
```

after developing the client and provider instances in a seed file, I get an empty set because the ids of different meeting times don't match (even if the day, start_time and end_time are the same). 
How could I resolve this issue? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You'll probably end up doing this with a SQL sub-query. I suggest you start looking there for an answer.

Comment: When you say `intersection`, do you mean exact equality of time and day? Or do you want to get even partial overlapping of time?

Comment: @StanislavMekhonoshin I simply mean, exact equality. i.e. 

(ta1.day == ta2.day) && (ta1.start_time == ta2.start_time) && (ta1.end_time == ta3.end_time)

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do:

```
intersections = client_instance1.meeting_times.reduce([]) do |result, client_meeting|
  intersects = provider_instance1.meeting_times.any? { |provider_meeting| provider_meeting.day == client_meeting.day && provider_meeting.start_time == client_meeting.start_time && provider_meeting.end_time == client_meeting.end_time }
  result << obj if intersects
  result
end
```

But following this approach, keep in mind, it'll return only `client_instance1` meetings, which have equivalent date/time in `provider_instance1` meetings.

The smarter approach - is to build a hash, where the keys will be a checksum of string like: `"#{day}#{start_time}#{end_time}"`.
And values - are arrays of equal meetings, both from client and providers meetings.